# Docker Engine API URL in mac

Tags: macos, docker, http

I'm trying to make HTTP requests to Docker Engine API but I'm getting a NotFound error

```
const response = await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: "http://unix:///var/run/docker.sock:/v1.39/images/create?fromImage=my-image&tag=latest",
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    });
```

This is the error I got.

```
code: 'ENOTFOUND',
syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
hostname: 'unix',
```

I have read some articles, apparently I have to edit a file called docker.service, but I'm not able to find it in MAC. Any idea

Comment: Your URL makes no sense. You have 2 schemes in a row. You'll want to add a real domainname at least after `http://`

Comment: Have you tried to put directly in `url` : "unix:///var/run/docker.sock" ?

Comment: Yes, didn't work. I had to install the package I mentioned below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way of doing this. I had to tnstall `socat` command:

`brew install socat`

Then I had to choose a port: (for example 8099)

`socat -d -d TCP-L:8099,fork UNIX:/var/run/docker.sock`

and then I was able to send request throught this URL

`tcp://localhost:8099`

Or

`http://localhost:8099`